# Getting an actual datetime from an initialization looking column -- pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with text and the datetime of its creation.

However, there is a problem with the datetime column:

```
     tweets                                             datetime
0   'Everybody...'  datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 29, 23, 25, 19)
1   'Good for ...'  datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 29, 22, 31, 26)
2   'tweeting ...'  datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 29, 21, 1, 21)
3   'rockets on...' datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 29, 20, 23, 57)
```

Is there a way to make that column into a "%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S" format?

Comment: Define "legible" and "usable".  Most people who work with datetime have no trouble reading this.  Most of all, since *you* know what you find usable, where is your code to perform the desired conversion, and what problem do you have with it?  `datetime` examples and specifications are easy to find on line.

Comment: In fact, those datetime objects make those dates actually *usable*. Bare strings to make the date look pretty have no meaning to Python, only to you. If you want to print them out somewhere, then do some kind of datetime to string conversion there.

Comment: I edited the post.. Im sorry for any confusion I caused. I looked up about this quite a bit and because I was in a bind, I used the words my peers use to describe similar situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on how they're currently displayed, it looks like those are literal strings instead of actual `datetime` objects. If so, convert them with some string manipulation:

```py
from datetime import datetime

df.datetime = df.datetime.apply(
    lambda x: datetime(*map(int, x.strip('datetime.datetime()').split(', '))))
```

Output:

```
            tweets             datetime
0   'Everybody...'  2020-08-29 23:25:19
1   'Good for ...'  2020-08-29 22:31:26
2   'tweeting ...'  2020-08-29 21:01:21
3  'rockets on...'  2020-08-29 20:23:57
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert them to datetime type with proper `format`:

```py
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], format='datetime.datetime(%Y, %m, %d, %H, %M, %S)')
```

```
print(df)

            tweets            datetime
0   'Everybody...' 2020-08-29 23:25:19
1   'Good for ...' 2020-08-29 22:31:26
2   'tweeting ...' 2020-08-29 21:01:21
3  'rockets on...' 2020-08-29 20:23:57
```